# How much precompiled headers affect mfc?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a C++ project in VC++ 2010 and I started it without precompiled headers. It was working fine, but when I added MFC multithreading to it, it started giving exceptions in afxmt.h. When I tested including afxmt.h in an another project WITH precompiled headers, it worked without any problems.

The question is, how would I get MFC (afxmt.h) working on the project that has no precompiled headers? Or should I just change it into one with precompiled headers?

EDIT:

These are the exceptions:

```
First-chance exception at 0x789394ea (mfc100ud.dll) in Quick_Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x77b015de in Quick_Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

These happen with empty projects (without precompiled headers).
The code for that is:

```
#include "afxmt.h"
```

Comment: Runtime exceptions, or compilation errors?  It would help if you can show the errors that you're seeing.

Comment: Edited the exceptions in to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The project using precompiled headers is automatically inserting #include afxmt.h; into compiling process for every source file.  If you aren't using precompiled headers you need to add that #include to every source file that is doing something that requires that header.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Precompiled header file is stadfx.h which has several other includes. You need to manually include the files containing all the function declaration that you use in your code if you are not using precompiled headers.